# How can I debug a failed in app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

From time to time, our users claim that they've made an in app purchase in our IOS application but they did not receive their product.

Our purchase flow goes like this:

1. Once the user purchases an item, the app makes a request to server including the transaction receipt.
2. Server saves this purchase with the transaction receipt in "new" state.
3. Server tries to verify this receipt on Apple servers.
4. If verification succeeds, the product is granted to user.
5. If verification succeeds, the purchase is marked as "Success".
6. If verification fails, the purchase is marked as "Fail".

On some occasions, we can find the purchase attempt in between one of these steps and we recover from there.

But sometimes we cannot find any purchase records relative to this user. I personally believe that most of our users are not lying but some bugs or network problems exist instead.

Is there a way I can debug these issues? Is there any information that I can request from the customer and compare that information to some records on iTunes pages or somewhere? Are we doing any mistake during our purchase process? What can we do better to prevent these issues?

### Edit

We are verifying purchases by making calls to Apple Api (by using We are verifying purchases by making calls to Apple api (by using nodejs's iap_verifier).

We do not handle any duplicates since we had none so far but I do not think that that is relevant for this specific case.

I understand that this might be an Apple outage, a problem on the Apple side, a network problem or any other problem that are not related to our servers. But I still need a way to confirm a user's purchase when he or she approaches us claiming that he or she made a purchase but did not get their product. Does such a way exist?

Comment: let's assume this is not an Apple outage. Could you explain more how are you verifying purchases from Apple servers? Do you handle overloads peacefully? Are you taking care of duplicates?

Comment: I assume they were still charged when the purchases failed ? The intermittence would suggest to me an Apple side problem ? Maybe erroneously reporting a success when in fact it wasn't & consequently not billing them ?>